# Two dropdowns populate userform

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently working on a costing web application for my workplace, i have two drop down boxes at the start of a userform, one is the for the class (150,300,....)& one is for the pipe size(1",2",3"...), once the user has selected "select from standard sizes" specified a class and pipe size, i want the rest of the form to auto populate using the dimensions stored in my models tables.

Below is the code for the view, im looking to auto fill kamm id, kamm od, spacer id ectttt with the correct dimension specified in the users selection, for example the user selects 1" 150 which in the table data has a kamm id of 15mm which i then want to be auto put into the user form.

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheets>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Iflexcst";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")






@using (Html.BeginForm("Iflexcst", "Costing", FormMethod.Post))
{


        <h2>Enter Dimensions:</h2>

    <h5>
       Select From Standard Sizes:
    </h5> @Html.CheckBox("Standard", false);

        <br>
    <h5> Select Class: </h5>  <br>
  @Html.DropDownList("Class", ViewData["class"] as List<SelectListItem>)
    <h5> Select Pipe: </h5> <br>
  @Html.DropDownList("Pipe", ViewData["pipe"] as List<SelectListItem>)
    <br>


            <br>
            <label for="NUM">Number of Sets:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="NUM" type="text" value=@ViewBag.Quantity name="Quan" /> 

            <br>
    <br>
            <label for="KID">Kamm ID:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />

    <br>
            <br><label for="KOD">Kamm OD:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="KOD" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammod name="kammod" />

            <br>
    <br>

            <label for="SID">Spacer Inner Dim:</label>
    <br>
            <input class ="foo" id="SID" type="text" name="SpacerInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.spacerid>
    <br>
             <br><label for="SOD">Spacer Outer Dim:</label>
    <br>
            <input class ="foo" id="SOD" type="text" name="SpacerOuterDim" value=@ViewBag.spacerod>
    <br>
            <br><label for="WOD">Washer Outer Dim:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="WOD" type="text" name="WashOuterDim" value=@ViewBag.washod>
    <br>
             <br><label for="IWI">Isolating Washer ID:</label>
    <br>
             <input class="foo" id="IWI" type="text" name="IsoWashInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.isoid>
    <br>
            <br><label for="SWI">Steel Washer ID:</label>
    <br>
             <input class="foo" id="SWI" type="text" name="SteelWashInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.steelid>
    <br>
             <br>

        <h2>Enter Materials:</h2>
        <br>
        <h5> Kamm Core: </h5>  <br>
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedCore", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets);
        <br>
        <h5> Spacer Core:</h5>   <br>
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedSpacer", (SelectList)ViewBag.SpacerSheets);
        <br>
        <h5> Kamm and Space Facing: </h5>   <br>
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets);
        <br>
        <h5>Steel Washer Core: </h5>     <br>
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedSteelCre", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets);
        <br>
        <h5> Isolating Washer Core: </h5>  <br>
        <h5> Special:</h5>     @Html.CheckBox("Bought in ISO washers?", false);
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedIsoCre", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets);
        <br>
        <h5>Isolating Washer Facing: </h5>   <br>
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedIsoFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets);
        <br>
        <h2>Washer and Sleeve Quantity and Prices:</h2>

        <br><label for="SWQ">Steel Washer Quantity:</label>
    <br>
    <input class="foo" id="SWQ" type="text" name="SteelWashQuan" value=@ViewBag.steelq>
        <br>    <br>

    <label for="IWQ">Isolating Washer Quantity:</label>
          <br>

    <input class="foo" id="IWQ" type="text" name="IsoWashQuan" value=@ViewBag.isoq>
        <br>

        <br>

    <label for="SQ">Sleeve Quantity:</label>
            <br>
    <input class="foo" id="SQ" type="text" name="SleeveQuan" value=@ViewBag.sleeveq>
        <br>

        <br>

    <label for="SP">Sleeve Price:</label>
     <br>
    <input class="foo" id="SP" type="text" name="SleevePrice" value=@ViewBag.sleevepr>
        <br>

        <br>


    <label for="IWP">Isolating Washer Price: </label>
         <br>
    <input class="foo" id="IWP" type="text" name="IsoPrice" value=@ViewBag.isopr>
        <br>

        <br>

                <label for="CS"> Cost</label>

        <br>
    <input class="foo" id="CS" type="number" value=@ViewBag.result />


                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


}

        <br><br><br><br>
```

Here is the code for my model, im looking to access the data from the classes onefifty, threehundred, sixhundred ect the dimensions.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication4.Models
{



    public class oneFifty
    {
        [Key]
        public int sizeID { get; set; }

        public int PipeSize { get; set; }

        public int KammID { get; set; }

        public int KammOD { get; set; }


        public int SpacerID { get; set; }

        public int SpacerOD { get; set; }
        public int WashersOD { get; set; }
        public int SteelWasherID { get; set; }
        public int IsoWasherID { get; set; }
        public int WasherQuan { get; set; }
        public int SleeveQuan { get; set; }

        public int FilamicSleeveCost { get; set; }

        public int G10SleeveCost { get; set; }
        public int G10WasherCost { get; set; }

    }



    public class threeHund
    {
        [Key]
        public int sizeID { get; set; }

        public int PipeSize { get; set; }



        public int KammID { get; set; }

        public int KammOD { get; set; }


        public int SpacerID { get; set; }

        public int SpacerOD { get; set; }
        public int WashersOD { get; set; }
        public int SteelWasherID { get; set; }
        public int IsoWasherID { get; set; }
        public int WasherQuan { get; set; }
        public int SleeveQuan { get; set; }

        public int FilamicSleeveCost { get; set; }

        public int G10SleeveCost { get; set; }
        public int G10WasherCost { get; set; }

    }
    public class sixHund
    {
        [Key]
        public int sizeID { get; set; }

        public int PipeSize { get; set; }


        public int KammID { get; set; }

        public int KammOD { get; set; }


        public int SpacerID { get; set; }

        public int SpacerOD { get; set; }
        public int WashersOD { get; set; }
        public int SteelWasherID { get; set; }
        public int IsoWasherID { get; set; }
        public int WasherQuan { get; set; }
        public int SleeveQuan { get; set; }

        public int FilamicSleeveCost { get; set; }

        public int G10SleeveCost { get; set; }
        public int G10WasherCost { get; set; }

    }
    public class nineHund
    {
        [Key]
        public int sizeID { get; set; }

        public int PipeSize { get; set; }


        public int KammID { get; set; }

        public int KammOD { get; set; }


        public int SpacerID { get; set; }

        public int SpacerOD { get; set; }
        public int WashersOD { get; set; }
        public int SteelWasherID { get; set; }
        public int IsoWasherID { get; set; }
        public int WasherQuan { get; set; }
        public int SleeveQuan { get; set; }

        public int FilamicSleeveCost { get; set; }

        public int G10SleeveCost { get; set; }
        public int G10WasherCost { get; set; }

    }

    public class fifteenhundred
    {
        [Key]
        public int sizeID { get; set; }

        public int PipeSize { get; set; }



        public int KammID { get; set; }

        public int KammOD { get; set; }


        public int SpacerID { get; set; }

        public int SpacerOD { get; set; }
        public int WashersOD { get; set; }
        public int SteelWasherID { get; set; }
        public int IsoWasherID { get; set; }
        public int WasherQuan { get; set; }
        public int SleeveQuan { get; set; }

        public int FilamicSleeveCost { get; set; }

        public int G10SleeveCost { get; set; }
        public int G10WasherCost { get; set; }

    }








    public class CoreSheetsDBContext : DbContext
    {


        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication4.Models.oneFifty> oneFifties { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication4.Models.threeHund> threeHunds { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication4.Models.sixHund> sixHunds { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication4.Models.nineHund> nineHunds { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication4.Models.fifteenhundred> fifteenhundreds { get; set; }


    }




}
```

If you help me drag threw one piece of data from the table based on the two drop down selections i should be able to do the rest with ease!

Thanks for reading and any help in advance, any other snippets required i will update the original question,

Cheers

EDIT added controller selectlist code below

public ActionResult Iflexcst()
        {

```
        CoreSheetsDBContext db = new CoreSheetsDBContext();





        List<SelectListItem> ClassSize = new List<SelectListItem>();

        ClassSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Class", Value = "0" });

        ClassSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "150", Value = "1" });

        ClassSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "300", Value = "2" });

        ClassSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "600", Value = "3" });

        ClassSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "900", Value = "4" });

        ClassSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1500", Value = "5" });



        ViewData["class"] = ClassSize;

        List<SelectListItem> PipeSize = new List<SelectListItem>();

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Pipe", Value = "0" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0.5", Value = "1" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0.75", Value = "2" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "3" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1.25", Value = "4" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1.5", Value = "5" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "6" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2.5", Value = "7" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "8" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "4", Value = "9" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "10" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "6", Value = "11" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "8", Value = "12" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "13" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "12", Value = "14" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "14", Value = "15" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "16", Value = "16" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "18", Value = "17" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "20", Value = "18" });

        PipeSize.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "24", Value = "19" });

        ViewData["pipe"] = PipeSize;



        return View(db.CoreSheets.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Okay! but why are you shouting....?;)

Comment: Cut the code down to the minimum relevant to your issue.

Comment: haha jai, and I've cut it down abit Stephen, its just a userform with a few drop downs and the model data, the dropdowns are generated from select lists in my controller